# Can an AWS Athena query read from S3 through an S3 Object Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I understand I can write an S3 Object Lambda which can transparently alter the returned S3 contents on the fly during retrieval, without modifying the original object.

I understand also that Athena can read json or csv files from S3.

My question is, can both of these capabilities be combined, so that Athena queries would read data which is transparently altered on the fly via S3 Object Lambda prior to being parsed by Athena?

*SOME CODE*

Suppose I write a CSV file:

`hello`

`world`

Then I write an S3 Object lambda:

```
import boto3
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

    object_get_context = event["getObjectContext"]
    request_route = object_get_context["outputRoute"]
    request_token = object_get_context["outputToken"]
    s3_url = object_get_context["inputS3Url"]

    # Get object from S3
    response = requests.get(s3_url)
    original_object = response.content.decode('utf-8')

    # Transform object
    transformed_object = original_object.upper()

    # Write object back to S3 Object Lambda
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.write_get_object_response(
        Body=transformed_object,
        RequestRoute=request_route,
        RequestToken=request_token)

    return {'status_code': 200}
```

(astute readers will notice this is the example from aws docs)

Now suppose I create an Athena EXTERNAL table and write this query:

```
SELECT * from hello
```

How can I ensure that the Athena query will return `WORLD` instead of `world` in this scenario?